# Beego:Display logged in username taken from input field of form

Tags: go, web-frameworks, beego

I am using Beego framework for my purpose and i have two html view files one is login and other is landing
login.html

```html
<form action="/commonDashboard" name="loginForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="loginForm" >
             <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your user name" id="userName" name="userName" taborder="1">
                <input type="password" class="qwerty" placeholder="Enter your password" id="userPassword" name="userPassword" taborder="2">
                <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="validatelogin();" taborder="3">
                <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="resetForm();" taborder="3">
    <span class="forgot"><a href="#">forgot password ?</a></span>
            <!-- Virtual Keyboard -->
                <span class="virtual"><a href="#" id="passwd" class="tooltip-tipsy" title="Click to open the virtual keyboard">Virtual Keyboard  
    </span>
            </form>
```

and landing page is

```html
<header class="top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <aside class="logo"><img src="img.jpg"  class="img-responsive"></aside>
        
        <aside class="top-right">
         <div class="profile">
             <ul>
                 <li class="name"><img src="../static/img/profile-img.jpg" alt="Shri Ram"> Hi <a href="#">Shri</a></li>
                    <li class="logout"><a href="/login">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="login-time">
             <ul>
                 <li><span>Current Login:</span> Mon 22 Sep 2014 03:28 PM</li>
                    <li class="last"><span>Last Login:</span> Sun 21 Sep 2014 02:28 PM</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
</header>
```

and controller is as follows

```html
package controllers

import (
 "fmt"
 "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type MainController struct {
 beego.Controller
}

func (c *MainController) Get() {
 c.TplNames = "login.html"
 fmt.Println("login Get Method")
}

type LoginController struct {
 beego.Controller
}

func (c *LoginController) Post() {
 c.TplNames = "commonDashboard.html"
 fmt.Println("this is dashboard")
 password := c.Input().Get("userPassword")
 username := c.GetSession("userName").(string)
 c.SetSession("userName", username)
 c.Data["user"] = username
 fmt.Println("password:" + " " + password)
}

type HeaderController struct {
 beego.Controller
}

func (c *HeaderController) Get() {
 fmt.Println("this is Header")
 username := c.Input().Get("userName")
 fmt.Println(username)
 c.TplNames = "commonHeader.html"
}

type FooterController struct {
 beego.Controller
}

func (c *FooterController) Get() {
 fmt.Println("this is footer")
 c.TplNames = "commonFooter.html"
}

type MenuController struct {
 beego.Controller
}

func (c *MenuController) Get() {
 fmt.Println("this is menu")
 c.TplNames = "commonMenu.html"
}
```

i want to display the currently logged in username in header of html file

Comment: why no replies for this question. what is the problem with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable *session* support in `app.conf` with:

```
sessionon = true
```

Save the username into session if login is valid:

```
func (c *LoginController) Post() {
    var json JsonObject
    u := &User{}
    if err := c.ParseForm(u); err != nil {
        json = JsonObject{
            Success: false,
            Message: "Server error",
        }
    } else {
        if u.Username == "admin" && u.Password == "123456" {
            json = JsonObject{
                Success: true,
            }
            // successfully login, put the user into session, you may put just username in
            c.SetSession("User", u)
        } else {
            json = JsonObject{
                Success: false,
                Message: "Incorrect username or password",
            }
        }
    }
    c.Data["json"] = json
    c.ServeJson()
}
```

Then you can recover the username in every `Controller`:

```
func (c *IndexController) Get() {
    // get user from session, you may get just username
    u := c.GetSession("User")
    if u == nil {
        c.Redirect("/login", 302)
    }
    // set user from session into response data
    c.Data["User"] = u
    c.TplNames = "index.html"
}
```

Get it on the html with template format:

```
{{ .User.username }}
```

You can just use `{{ .userName }}`

Comment: thanks . I AM getting error: incompatible types in binary expression
  fmt.Println("username:" + " " + username)

Comment: @VijayKumar `username := c.GetSession(<key>).(string)` Remember that golang is sensitive with type. While `GetSession` returns a type of `interface{}`, you should explicitly convert it to the type which you set into session.

Comment: i am trying it like this                                                          username := c.GetSession(userName).(string)
c.Data["user"] = username

Comment: its giving this error now even though field name is same as i have mentioned                                                                                       error: reference to undefined name ‘userName’
  username := c.GetSession(userName).(string)

Comment: and when i try this                                                             username := c.GetSession("userName").(string)
c.Data["user"] = username                                                                                  i got this error on browsers display                                                --Handler crashed with error interface conversion: interface is nil, not string

Comment: @VijayKumar Make sure that you've set the `userName` into session by `c.SetSession("userName", <value>)` while doing login.

Comment: shall i put all controller code for better undersanding.

Comment: That would be better, login controller and the controller which you want to use `username`.

Comment: still its the same. Can you please specify that in your answer. Field name is userName.

Comment: can you see my updated question where i have updated my controllers.

Comment: i want to display that username in landing page particularly in header

Comment: but  no where &User is defined

Comment: well, you should change it into a simple string, `User` is a struct I define.